# Completely Remove Desura

Tags: games

I'd like to completely remove Desura and any downloaded games.

As far as I can see, the only way to do this successfully is to go through the home folder manually removing the various files/folders.

Is this correct? Is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 5):

In the readme file that comes with Desura the instructions are as follows:

1. To remove the menu icon, first run

   ```
   xdg/xdg-desktop-menu uninstall --mode user desura.desktop
   ```

   from inside the Desura installation directory
2. Delete the `desura` folder which contains the program contents.
3. As an added step I would suggest removing the `~/.desura` folder

That should be all

Answer (score 1):

Delete `~/bin/desura`.

This folder contains all the games and the client itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your action is correct. There is no other way to remove Desura. 
Maybe check on your /home, if there is an hiden folder called ".desura". And remove it. Dusura should be completely remove after that.

Answer (score 0):

this is the simpler way to do that .
Firstly u find where these **desura** folders are

so type in terminal

```
find desura
```

it will shows u all possible result go to that place manually and delete all files .
hope this will solve problem